# I am having this error "canOpenURL: failed for URL :com.appcoda.gsignin"

Tags: ios, swift2

"-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.appcoda.gsignin://a" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.appcoda.gsignin"
'Your app must support the following URL schemes: com.appcoda.gsignin,'

Comment: you need to set URLScheme in your info.plist file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// you need to add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist ,
for more information  refer fllowing link , the following attachment will help you

http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes

[image]